# Issue with module hierarchy in Python

Tags: python, fastapi, openapi-generator, modulenotfounderror

```
mt-kart
     |
      --> src/data_kart
     |        |
     |         --> apis
     |        |       |
     |        |        --> __init__.py
     |        |        --> endpoints.py
     |        |
     |         --> models
     |        |       |
     |        |        --> __init__.py
     |        |        --> modelx.py
     |        |
     |         --> defaults.py
     |         --> main.py
      --> tests
             |
              --> __init__.py
             |
              --> conftest.py
             |
              --> test_others.py
```

1. 

In `main.py` I get `module not found error` when I try to refer

`from defaults import func1`

But this works

`from .defaults import func1`

It should work without "." right?

2.

From `endpoints.py` how should I refer the `modelx.py`? My prev. developer had it like below.

`from data_kart.models.modelx import model1`

But it complains when I run some tests using `pytest` from `mt-kart` directory. Then the below worked for `pytest`. But i am afraid it may give error in some different scenario.

`from src.data_kart.models.modelx import model1`

The project uses `FastApi` and `OpenApI Code generators`

**Edit-------------------**

In `conftest.py` I added `src` to `sys.path` and the paths are working fine for my issue `2`.
`sys.path.append(os.getcwd()+"/src")`

Answer (score 0):

You could instead add the directory including your package in [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71342222/17865804). For example, if you are on Windows, the directory of your package should look something like this: `C:/users/.../mt-kart/src`. After adding the path to the environment variable, please make sure to start a new terminal to lunch `pytest`.

By adding `C:/users/.../mt-kart/src` in `PYTHONPATH`, it means that you can import your modules like this: `from data_kart.models.modelx import model1` (as your  *previous developer* did) and `from defaults import func1` should work as expected. Every time you import a module from the `data_kart` package, it will point to the directory given in the `PYTHONPATH` variable. Hence, there would be no need to add `sys.path.append(...` to the top of each file in your project (or test files) to import modules.