# ModuleNotFoundError when trying to unpickle a model in Flask app

Tags: python, flask, pickle

Python version: 3.6.9

I've used `pickle` to dump a machine learning model into a file, and when I try to run a prediction on it using Flask, it fails with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'predictors'`. How can I fix this error so that it recognizes my model, whether I try to run a prediction via Flask or via the Python command (e.g. `python predict_edu.py`)?

Here is my file structure:

```
 - video_discovery
   __init__.py
   - data_science
     - model
     - __init__.py
     - predict_edu.py
     - predictors.py
     - train_model.py
```

Here's my predict_edu.py file:

```
import pickle

with open('model', 'rb') as f:
        bow_model = pickle.load(f)
```

Here's my predictors.py file:

```
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin

# Basic function to clean the text
def clean_text(text):
    # Removing spaces and converting text into lowercase
    return text.strip().lower()

# Custom transformer using spaCy
class predictor_transformer(TransformerMixin):
    def transform(self, X, **transform_params):
        # Cleaning Text
        return [clean_text(text) for text in X]

    def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        return self

    def get_params(self, deep=True):
        return {}
```

Here's how I train my model:

```
python data_science/train_model.py
```

Here's my train_model.py file:

```
from predictors import predictor_transformer

# pipeline = Pipeline([("cleaner", predictor_transformer()), ('vectorizer', bow_vector), ('classifier', classifier_18p)])
pipeline = Pipeline([("cleaner", predictor_transformer())])

with open('model', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(pipeline, f)
```

My Flask app is in: `video_discovery/__init__.py`

Here's how I run my Flask app:

```
FLASK_ENV=development FLASK_APP=video_discovery flask run
```

I believe the issue may be occurring because I'm training the model by running the Python script directly instead of using Flask, so there might be some namespace issues, but I'm not sure how to fix this. It takes a while to train my model, so I can't exactly wait on an HTTP request.

What am I missing that might fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html:

> `pickle` can save and restore class instances transparently, however the class definition must be importable and live in the same module as when the object was stored.

When you run `python data_science/train_model.py` and import `from predictors`, Python imports `predictors` as a top-level module and `predictor_transformer` is in that module.

However, when you run a prediction via Flask from the parent folder of `video_discovery`, `predictor_transformer` is in the `video_discovery.data_science.predictors` module.

## Use relative imports and run from a consistent path

**train_model.py**: Use relative import

```py
# from predictors import predictor_transformer  # -
from .predictors import predictor_transformer   # +
```

**Train model**: Run `train_model` with `video_discovery` as top-level module

```sh
# python data_science/train_model.py                # -
python -m video_discovery.data_science.train_model  # +
```

**Run a prediction via a Python command**: Run `predict_edu` with `video_discovery` as top-level module

```sh
# python predict_edu.py                             # -
python -m video_discovery.data_science.predict_edu  # +
```

**Run a prediction via Flask**: (no change, already run with `video_discovery` as top-level module)

```sh
FLASK_ENV=development FLASK_APP=video_discovery flask run
```

Comment: Thank you very much @aaron! This worked. I appreciate the explanation as to why my current code isn't working, especially the snippet from the pickle documentation (which I had tried to find before)!

Answer (score 2):

It seems a bit strange that you get that error when executing `predict_edu.py`, as it is in the same directory as `predictors.py`, and thus, using absolute import such as `from predictors import predictor_transformer` (without the dot `.` operator) should normally work as expected. However, below are a few options that you could try out, if the error persists.

### Option 1

You could add the parent directory of the `predictors` file to the system `PATH` variable, before attempting to import the module, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71080756/17865804). This should work fine for smaller projects.

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
sys.path.insert(0, str(Path(__file__).resolve().parent))
from predictors import predictor_transformer
```

### Option 2

Use relative imports, e.g., `from .predictors import...`, and make sure you run the script from the parent directory of your package, as shown below. The [`-m` option](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m) "searches the [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) for the named module and execute its contents as the [`__main__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html#module-__main__) module", and not as the top-level script. Read more about the `-m` option in the following references: [[1]](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610001/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-m-switch), [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52441280/what-does-the-m-option-stand-for-in-python), [[4]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241420/execution-of-python-code-with-m-option-or-not), [[5]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50821312/meaning-of-python-m-flag), [[6]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46319694/what-does-it-mean-to-run-library-module-as-a-script-with-the-m-option). Read more about "relative imports" here: [[1]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/159503/whats-wrong-with-relative-imports-in-python), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918539/can-anyone-explain-pythons-relative-imports), [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3), [[4]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time).

```
python -m video_discovery.data_science.predict_edu
```

However, the [PEP 8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) recommends using absolute imports in general.

> Absolute imports are recommended, as they are usually more readable
> and tend to be better behaved (or at least give better error messages)
> if the import system is incorrectly configured (such as when a
> directory inside a package ends up on sys.path)

In certain cases, however, absolute imports can get quite verbose, depending on the complexity of the directory structure, as shown below. On the other hand, "relative imports can be messy, particularly for shared projects where directory structure is likely to change". They are also "not as readable as absolute ones, and it is hard to tell the location of the imported resources". Read more about [Python Import](https://realpython.com/python-import/) and [Absolute vs Relative Imports](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/).

```
from package1.subpackage2.subpackage3.subpackage4.module5 import function6
```

### Option 3

Include the directory containing your package directory in [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) and use absolute imports instead. `PYTHONPATH` is used to set the path for user-defined modules, so that they can be directly imported into a Python script. The `PYTHONPATH` variable is a string with a list of directories that need to be added to the [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) directory list by Python. The primary use of this variable is to allow users to import modules that have not yet made into an installable Python package. Read more about it [here](https://bic-berkeley.github.io/psych-214-fall-2016/using_pythonpath.html) and [here](https://bic-berkeley.github.io/psych-214-fall-2016/sys_path.html).

For instance, let’s say you have a package named `video_discovery` (under `/Users/my_user/code/video_discovery`) and wanted to add the directory `/Users/my_user/code` to the `PYTHONPATH`:

**On Mac**

1. Open `Terminal.app`
2. Open the file `~/.bash_profile` in your text editor – e.g. `atom ~/.bash_profile`
3. Add the following line to the end: `export PYTHONPATH="/Users/my_user/code"`
4. Save the file.
5. Close `Terminal.app`
6. Start `Terminal.app` again, to read in the new settings, and type
   `echo $PYTHONPATH`. It should show something like `/Users/my_user/code`.

**On Linux**

1. Open your favorite terminal program
2. Open the file `~/.bashrc` in your text editor – e.g. `atom ~/.bashrc`
3. Add the following line to the end: `export PYTHONPATH=/home/my_user/code`
4. Save the file.
5. Close your terminal application.
6. Start your terminal application again, to read in the new settings,
   and type `echo $PYTHONPATH`. It should show something like `/home/my_user/code`.

**On Windows**

1. Open `This PC` (or `Computer`), right-click inside and select
   `Properties`.
2. From the computer properties dialog, select `Advanced system settings` on the left.
3. From the advanced system settings dialog, choose the `Environment variables` button.
4. In the Environment variables dialog, click the `New` button **in the
   top half of the dialog**, to make a new **user variable**:
5. Give the variable *name* as `PYTHONPATH` and in *value* add the path to
   your module directory. Choose `OK` and `OK` again to save this variable.
6. Now open a cmd window and type `echo %PYTHONPATH%` to confirm the environment variable is correctly set. **Remember** to open a new cmd window to run your Python program, so that it picks up the new settings in `PYTHONPATH`.

### Option 4

Another solution would be to install the package in an editable state (all edits made to the .py files will be automatically included in the installed package), as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50193944) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50194143). However, the amount of work required to get this to work might make Option 3 a better choice for you.

The contents for the `setup.py` should be as shown below, and the command for installing the package should be `pip install -e .` (`-e` flag stands for "editable" and `.` stands for "current directory").

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(name='myproject', version='1.0', packages=find_packages())
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you for your detailed answer! I think all of these options would work well for me, especially #1 and #2. It was a tough decision, but I had to give the answer to aaron because I received more information regarding the issue. Still, your solution would work well for me, and I really appreciate your help.