# I can not run fastapi and pytest at the same time due to an import module error

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, fastapi

I'm having a circular problem that I'm not able to solve.
I started my project as follows:

```sh
.
├── conf
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── server.py
├── __init__.py
├── main.py
├── requirements.txt
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── v1
        ├── __init__.py
        └── test_item.py
```

In `main.py` I have:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn

from conf.server import HOST, PORT

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host=HOST, port=PORT, reload=True)
```

In `test_main.py`

```py
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

from main import app

client = TestClient(app)


def test_read_main():
    response = client.get("/")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == {"message": "Hello World"}
```

The error I get when I run the script from the same level as `main.py` with `pytest`:

```py
C:\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests\v1\test_item.py:3: in <module>
    from main import app
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'
```

If I write the name of the folder before main:

```py
from api.main import app
```

I get an error with the con/server.py module:

```py
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
C:\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests\v1\test_item.py:3: in <module>
    from api.main import app
main.py:4: in <module>
    from conf.server import HOST, PORT
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conf'
```

If I now change in main to include the name of the folder:

```py
from api.conf.server import HOST, PORT
```

The test finally works, but now If I try to run the server wiht `python main.py` it will not work anymore:

```py
    from api.conf.server import HOST, PORT
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api'
```

What I'm doing wrong to get into this loop?

Answer (score 0):

Your should import your modules using absolute imports, as you already described in the final part of your question:

```
from api.main import app
from api.conf.server import HOST, PORT
```

and make sure to include the directory containing your package directory in [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71342222/17865804) (Option 3). Then, you should be able to run your script. Other options listed in the above link might help you as well.

Answer (score 0):

run

```
python -m main
```

instead of

```
python main.py
```