# ModuleNotFoundError in Python application with FastAPI

Tags: python, python-import, fastapi, importerror, python-module

I'm making Todo fullstack application with Python FastAPI backend. I'm working on Windows 10. I'm using this structure:

```
.backend
|   .dockerignore
|   .env
|   .gitignore
|   Dockerfile
|   requirements.txt
|
\---app
    |   database.py
    |   main.py
    |   __init__.py
    |
    +---models
    |       auth.py
    |       todo.py
    |       __init__.py
    |
    +---routes
    |       auth.py
    |       todo.py
    |       __init__.py
    |
    \---services
            auth.py
            todo.py
            __init__.py
```

app/main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

from app.routes import todo


app = FastAPI(title="Todo")

app.include_router(todo.router)

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```

From backend directory `uvicorn app.main:app --reload` gives `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'`

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mabes\python310\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\mabes\python310\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mabes\Desktop\todo-fullstack\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\_subprocess.py", line 76, in subprocess_started     
    target(sockets=sockets)
  File "C:\Users\mabes\Desktop\todo-fullstack\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 61, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
  File "C:\Users\mabes\python310\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\mabes\python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\mabes\Desktop\todo-fullstack\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 68, in serve
    config.load()
  File "C:\Users\mabes\Desktop\todo-fullstack\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\config.py", line 467, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
  File "C:\Users\mabes\Desktop\todo-fullstack\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\importer.py", line 24, in import_from_string        
    raise exc from None
  File "C:\Users\mabes\Desktop\todo-fullstack\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\importer.py", line 21, in import_from_string        
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
  File "C:\Users\mabes\python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\mabes\Desktop\todo-fullstack\backend\app\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from app.routes import todo
  File "C:\Users\mabes\Desktop\todo-fullstack\backend\app\routes\todo.py", line 4, in <module>
    from models.todo import Todo, TodoCreate, TodoUpdate
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'
```

From backend/app directory `uvicorn main:app --reload` gives `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'`

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mabes\python310\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\mabes\python310\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mabes\Desktop\todo-fullstack\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\_subprocess.py", line 76, in subprocess_started     
    target(sockets=sockets)
  File "C:\Users\mabes\Desktop\todo-fullstack\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 61, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
  File "C:\Users\mabes\python310\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\mabes\python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\mabes\Desktop\todo-fullstack\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 68, in serve
    config.load()
  File "C:\Users\mabes\Desktop\todo-fullstack\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\config.py", line 467, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
  File "C:\Users\mabes\Desktop\todo-fullstack\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\importer.py", line 24, in import_from_string        
    raise exc from None
  File "C:\Users\mabes\Desktop\todo-fullstack\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\importer.py", line 21, in import_from_string        
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
  File "C:\Users\mabes\python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\mabes\Desktop\todo-fullstack\backend\app\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from app.routes import todo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

I've tried command `set PYTHONPATH=$PWD`. Nothing changes.

This import system makes me sad.

Comment: You should post the code on `main.py`, if you can use `tree` command it'll print out the folder structure nicely.

Comment: Should work. Unless the folder being named `app` is making things weird. Post full stack  traces to see where the error is.

Comment: Thanks for helping, man. I posted full tracebacks.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71360330/17865804) answer your question? Related answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71080756/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71342222/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73647164/17865804)

Comment: If you run from inside the `app` directory (`uvicorn main:app --reload`) it will work...

Comment: I've added system environment variable `PYTHONPATH` with value `C:\Users\mabes\Desktop\todo-fullstack\backend`. Now it's working with `uvicorn app.main:app --reload` from backend directory, but still not working from app directory with `uvicorn app.main:app --reload`. I'm glad that it works for you, Matteo. But for me it's not.

Comment: You might not need the `app` in `from app.routes import todo` try `from routes import todo`

Comment: Someone who knows about imports, relative imports, etc... more than me will probably help you out. If you search ´relative imports FastAPI´ in SO you might find an answer.

Comment: Thanks to all. Now my system environment variable `PYTHONPATH` is `C:\Users\mabes\Desktop\todo-fullstack\backend\app`. I've updated import in `main.py`: `from routes import todo` like Daviid suggested. Now it works from backend and app directories.